# SonataAdmin, add menu on left

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm working on Symfony2 and SonataAdminBundle.

I need to know how to add a menu in the left part of my dashboard ? Like in the screen :

[image]

I need to have the Dashboard block in the left part on the page (in dark-grey on my screen).. how can i do that ?

you can see on the demo of SonataAdmin http://demo.sonata-project.org/admin/dashboard, login admin, apssword admin

Comment: What version of sonata-admin do you run ? because its only on the last one ( not official ) . It should be something to configure with knp menu, official doc doesn t talk about it yet

Comment: i have dev-master in my composer.json

Comment: If you have time, you can add https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle and see what s they do to add items on left menu. will you be kind to post your final answer ? i m curious to see how customize it :) you can have a look in directory named "menu" , there is event that manages side menu

Comment: Can u plz choose correct answer?

Answer (score 10):

http://blog.eike.se/2014/03/custom-page-controller-in-sonata-admin.html

this post helped me.

extend template

```
vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig
```

override block

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}
{% block side_bar_after_nav %}
YOUR CUSTOM MENU
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works. The link mentions `top_bar_after_nav` but it has been renamed to `side_bar_after_nav`.

Answer (score 7):

I've just added ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN to ROLE_ADMIN in security.yml:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
```

and it shown up, finaly. For more info check this: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2321

Answer (score 6):

The first thing to do is to open this file in this path:

\wamp\www\YourProject\vendor\sonata-project\admin-bundle\Resources\view \standard_layout.html.twig

Then look for :`ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN` (using Ctrl+F) then changed to the role that you are using to log in to your admin dashboard for me I'm using `ROLE_ADMIN`, then save the file, close it, check your admin dashboard, you will find exactly what you look for.

hope it will works

Comment: Or you could just extend `ROLE_ADMIN` from `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN` in your `security.yml`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer but for the comment above extending ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN instead!

Comment: Never touch the vendors directly. Always try to use bundle inheritance to make your application as reusable as possible.

Answer (score 2):

well, if you want to use the automatic menu generated by sonata you can use this steps to reach the point:

**Solution**

1. override the default sonata layout twig file from `config.yml`

   ```
   sonata_admin:
       templates:
           layout:                         ::layout.html.twig
   ```
2. your `::layout.html.twig`:

   ```
   {% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}

   {% block side_bar_nav %}
       {{ knp_menu_render('sonata_admin_sidebar', {template: sonata_admin.adminPool.getTemplate('knp_menu_template')}) }}
   {% endblock %}
   ```

**Why this solution?**

since the default `SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig` checks the user to have the `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN` permission (and you might not using `sonata user bundle`), you need to override permission checking process, which is by default:

```
{% block side_bar_nav %}
    {% if app.user and is_granted('ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN') %}
        {{ knp_menu_render('sonata_admin_sidebar', {template: sonata_admin.adminPool.getTemplate('knp_menu_template')}) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock side_bar_nav %}
```

I think this is the easiest way to use navigation buttons on left sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

okay finally,

it seems they updated sonata admin bundle doc,

take a look at this => http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/architecture.html

or with user bundle :

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/user_dashboard.html

hope it will works

Comment: I'm not using userbundle, and i don't know how the doc can help me in my case ?

Comment: there is a "menu" configuration below "dashboard" to add to you config.yml , even if it design for sonata admin bundle 2.3 , it worths to try to see if it works in the beta preview :)

Answer (score 0):

Do two things:

1. Create a template called `standard_layout.html.twig` in your custom bundle's `Resources/views` folder. Add this to that template:

   `{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}
   {% block side_bar_nav %}
   //add your code here
   {% endblock side_bar_nav %}`

**PS:** Look at block `side_bar_nav` in `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig` for direction

2. In `app/config/config.yml` (or wherever your config file is), add:

`sonata_admin:
        templates:
            layout: YourBundle::standard_layout.html.twig`

I recommend using `YourBundle:Admin:standard_layout.html.twig` to organize all your admin templates into a single `Admin` folder. You'd need to change the location of the template in step 1 accordingly